# Algolia API request to add attribute for faceting with PHP laravel

Tags: php, laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I'm looking for some API request from PHP Laravel backend, which will add some new attribute to all my indices (including replicas) to attributes for faceting. Is there any option for this?

Exact case:
In e-commerce administration I create new Product Attribute (for example color) and I attach it to Product Model. In toSearchableAttributes method I have function, which will dynamically add these attributes to array and they will sync to algolia. This is working well, but I need to add this newly created attribute to algolia's Facets.
So I think, it would be best if I call some request to algolia when I store newly created attribute to my DB. Does Algolia have API for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
    $client = \Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\SearchClient::create('APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET');
    $index = $client->initIndex('MAIN_INDEX_NAME');

    $attributesForFaceting = $index->getSettings()['attributesForFaceting'];
    $attributesForFaceting[] = 'searchable('.$newAttributeName.')';

    $index->setSettings([
        'attributesForFaceting' => $attributesForFaceting
    ]);

    foreach($index->getSettings()['replicas'] as $replicaName) {
        $index = $client->initIndex($replicaName);
        $index->setSettings([
            'attributesForFaceting' => $attributesForFaceting
        ]);
    }
```